# Using Conditional Formatting with Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with approximately 2000 rows.  I want to color code the rows based on the following conditions:

> If T2 is less than U2, color the row
>   red; if T2 is greater than U2, color
>   the row green; and if U2 is empty,
>   color the row blue.

Please tell me how to write it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2003:

- Select T2
- Format -> Conditional Formatting...
- Add the first condition to set background to red, with condition less than, and value =U2
- Click "Add > >" twice to add two more conditions, one for the greater-than case, and one for the empty case (condition equal to, value ="")

Click OK.